# Use apply lambda with if else conditional without computing the condition twice

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

Is there a way to apply the lambda statement without having to compute the `x.split(' ')[0]` twice?  I know it can be done using a function i.e. `.apply(lambda x: pre_dir(x)` and take care of the logic there, but wondering if it can be done in a one-liner.

```
address.insert(6, 'PRE_DIR', address['STREETNAME'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0] if x.split(' ')[0] in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'] else ''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `where` instead of `apply`. In other words, replace

```
address['STREETNAME'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0] if x.split(' ')[0] in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'] else '')
```

by

```
address['STREETNAME'].str.split(' ').str[0].where(lambda x: x.isin(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W']), '')
```

Example: For the following DataFrame

```py
address = pd.DataFrame({'STREETNAME':['North Ave', '1st St', 'W 34th St']})
```

the above code produces the following column:

```
    0     
    1     
    2    W
```

Answer (score 0):

with python ≥ 3.8 you can use a [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/):

```
lambda x: y if (y:=x.split(' ')[0]) in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'] else '')
```

That said, IIUC, you could use a regex here:

```
address['STREETNAME'].str.extract('^([NSEW]) ').fillna('')
```

Comment: this would not work for my situation as not all road names start with NSEW, but any road name could contain those letters

Comment: @InfinityCliff you mean the second approach? The first one should give the exact same result as the other answer, just avoiding to compute the `split` twice unnecessarily ;)